# ion auth forgot password mail not received in mail account

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, email, ion-auth

In ion auth my forgot password mail sent successfully but not received in my email account...
I have searched many tutorials but can't find any solution.

Please Help me to solve this.

my email config file

```html
$config['email_config'] = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'protocol' => 'smtp',

    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => '465',
    'smtp_user' => 'k10kevalam@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'k10@kevalam',

);
```

in ion_auth config

```html
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE; // Send Email using the builtin CI email class, if false it will return the code and the identity

$config['email_config'] = 'file';
```

in ion_auth.php library

```html
if ($this->email->send())
  {
             echo $this->email->print_debugger();
             $this->set_message('forgot_password_successful');
      return TRUE;
        }
```

display message :"email sent"

in my ion_auth.php controller

```html
function forgot_password()
 {
            {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('forgot_password_username_identity_label'), 'required');
  }
  else
  {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('forgot_password_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email');
  }


  if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
  {
   //setup the input
   $this->data['email'] = array('name' => 'email',
    'id' => 'email',
   );

   if ( $this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth') == 'username' ){
    $this->data['identity_label'] = $this->lang->line('forgot_password_username_identity_label');
   }
   else
   {
    $this->data['identity_label'] = $this->lang->line('forgot_password_email_identity_label');
   }

   //set any errors and display the form
   $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
   $this->_render_page('auth/forgot_password', $this->data);
  }
  else
  {
   // get identity from username or email
   if ( $this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth') == 'username' ){
    $identity = $this->ion_auth->where('username', strtolower($this->input->post('email')))->users()->row();
   }
   else
   {
    $identity = $this->ion_auth->where('email', strtolower($this->input->post('email')))->users()->row();
   }
              if(empty($identity)) {

               if($this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth') == 'username')
               {
                                   $this->ion_auth->set_message('forgot_password_username_not_found');
               }
               else
               {
                  $this->ion_auth->set_message('forgot_password_email_not_found');
               }

                  $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                  redirect("auth/forgot_password", 'refresh');
              }

   //run the forgotten password method to email an activation code to the user
   $forgotten = $this->ion_auth->forgotten_password($identity->{$this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth')});

   if ($forgotten)
   {
    //if there were no errors
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    
                                redirect("auth/login", 'refresh'); //we should display a confirmation page here instead of the login page
   }
   else
   {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                                    
                        redirect("auth/forgot_password", 'refresh');
   }
  }
 }
```

What should i change.?

Your Help would Be Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is just to create a test controller method that sends an email to work out the proper email settings.

Answer (score 0):

made one email file and changing some security in gmail...
in my email config file

```html
<?php
$config["mailtype"] = "html";
$config["protocol"] = "smtp";
$config["smtp_host"] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
$config["smtp_user"] = "xxxx@gmail.com";
$config["smtp_pass"] = "xxxx";
$config["smtp_port"] = 465;
$config["crlf"] = "\r\n";
$config["newline"] = "\r\n";
?>
```

suggest to made config file for email